# Slim jwt token(sent by axios request) not found

Tags: php, vue.js, jwt, axios, slim

I'm setting up a Vue js/Vuetify website with a [PHP Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) API, and [tuuopla slim-jwt-auth](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth) as a middleware for JWT token authentication.
The unprotected routes are working fine but when I try to send axios requests to the protected routes in the API I only got token not found error.

I dont know if the problem is at Vue js, axios or the API configuration. `curl` and Postman gives the decoded key as expected when acessing the protected route, only the Vue js website gives this errors.
To run the API I'm using PHP built-in server: `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/

In any case, the `localStorage.getItem("token")` does exist, as I tried to print them before every request as well in the interceptor.

Here is a test component :

```
<template>
 <v-btn @click="test">Test</v-btn>
 <v-btn @click="test2">Test</v-btn>
</template>
<script>
  methods: {
    test() {
      axios
        .post("api/user",{},{
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
            }
          }
        )
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },
    test2() {
      var yourConfig = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
      };
      axios
        .get("test", yourConfig)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  },
</script>
```

axios config(tried with and without the interceptor)

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    if (token) {
      config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    console.log(token)
    return config;
  },

  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Slim `index.php`(a protected and a unprotected sample routes for my tests)

```
...
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

$app->group('/api', function (\Slim\App $app) {
    $app->get('/user', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
        return $response->withJson($request->getAttribute('decoded_token_data'));
    });
});
$app->get('/test', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    return $response->withJson(["hi"=>"hello"]);
});

// Run app
$app->run();
```

`middleware.php`(tried many configurations)

```
<?php
// Application middleware
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;


$logger = new Logger("slim");
$rotating = new RotatingFileHandler(__DIR__ . "/logs/slim.log", 0, Logger::DEBUG);
$logger->pushHandler($rotating);

$app->add(new \Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "secure" => false,
    "logger" => $logger,
    "relaxed" => ["localhost:8080"],
    "attribute" => "decoded_token_data",
    "secret" => "mykey",
    "algorithm" => ["HS256"],
    "rules" => [
        new \Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication\RequestPathRule([
            // Degenerate access to '/api'
            "path" => ["/api"],
            // It allows access to 'login' without a token
            "passthrough" => [
                "/login_admin"
                //"/login_admin"
            ]
        ])
    ],
    "error" => function ($response, $arguments) {
        $data["status"] = "error";
        $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
        return $response
            ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
]));
```

The errors when tried to access the `api/user` route:

- Chrome console:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8000/api/user net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/user' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

- API Response:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Token not found."
}
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding

```
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

to your .htaccess file?